# How to choose the good Q&A site to ask a question about the complexity of a program?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've made an implementation of the [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) in Java and I would like to know how to calculate the complexity of the program.

I don't know if I have to ask it on SO, on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or on [CSTheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)?

**Is it rather a theoretical question or it's enough about code to be on SO?**

**EDIT :**

*Some precision :*

I will have to post my code in order to provide informations to calculate the complexity of the algorithm and measure the impact of my use of Java object on the complexity.

**So what is the more important?**

The technical part for calculate the complexity based on Java use? Or the theoretical issue of calculate complexity?

Comment: If you are expecting answers to discuss topics like cyclomatic complexity, your question might be more suitable for [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @YannisRizos I think about it too, I hope having some other clues. Let see what people think about it.

Comment: cstheory.se is for research-level questions, so definitely not there. SO might be okay, but that depends on what exactly and how you ask.

Comment: If you are facing a problem, e.g a specific bottleneck or something else that can be objectively solved and fixed, SO is the place. That being said, "How do I accurately calculate space / time complexity for any given algorithm" [didn't go over so well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449426/how-to-calculate-time-and-space-complexity-of-algorithms) the last time it was asked, because it was asked quite poorly. Note, it wasn't closed as off topic, but NARQ. Give it your best shot on SO, the worst case is we help you edit it and perhaps migrate it to PSE if needed.

Comment: Also note, [it has been covered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968683/how-to-calculate-complexity) but not quite in the context you're describing. Take care to make the question unique and awesome, and I suspect it'll do rather well.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for the tips. I will try to compose on SO an intelligible question that point up the impact of the Java code I used, on the (known) complexity of Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: Finally post on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332945/does-my-java-implementation-of-dijkstra-shortest-path-algorithm-affect-the-compl. And was closed as NARQ...